# How to create composite unique key in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, unique-key

Is it possible to create composite unique key in Hybris through `items.xml`?

In the given example:

```
        <itemtype  code="SimpleDevice">
            <deployment table="simpleDevice" typecode="20063"/>
            <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="productId" type="java.lang.String">
                    <persistence type="property" />
                    <modifiers unique="true" optional="false" initial="true"/>
                    <description>Device's product ID</description>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="serialNumber" type="java.lang.String">
                    <persistence type="property" />
                    <modifiers unique="true" optional="false" initial="true"/>
                    <description>Device's serial number</description>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </itemtype>
```

How do I combine the 2 attribute to make them behave as a composite unique key? My plan B it's to use some interceptor to check if such a combination already exists before creating it. But I want to avoid overloading the DB when importing several items by Impex.

Comment: In Hybris, if you declare multiple unique keys then it behaves like a composite unique key. Hence what you have mentioned is correct only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add new unique index in indexes element for using multiple attributes together in an index.

```
<itemtype  code="SimpleDevice">
    <deployment table="simpleDevice" typecode="20063"/>
    <attributes>
        <attribute qualifier="productId" type="java.lang.String">
            <persistence type="property" />
            <modifiers unique="true" optional="false" initial="true"/>
            <description>Device's product ID</description>
        </attribute>
        <attribute qualifier="serialNumber" type="java.lang.String">
            <persistence type="property" />
            <modifiers unique="true" optional="false" initial="true"/>
            <description>Device's serial number</description>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
    <indexes>
        <index name="SimpleDeviceIdx" unique="true">
            <key attribute="productId" />
            <key attribute="serialNumber" />
        </index>
    </indexes>  
</itemtype>
```

Comment: That's interesting. Ricardo's code worked using the in-memory DB. I haven't tested with a real DB like mySQL.

Comment: Should I still keep the <modifiers unique="true" ... for both of the attributes? Or only the index is enough? Won't they conflict?

Comment: No, because modifiers make every attribute unique separately.

Answer (score 1):

The given example is already correct. It makes the combination of productId and serialNumber unique.

Comment: Hi. With the given example I could not insert Product:1 - SerialNumber: 1 and Product1 - SerialNumber2. 

Because on the second example, I would already have Product = 1. Preventing me from using it with other serial number combinations.

Comment: @RicardoMachado I tested it, and it works: https://imgur.com/HAoaoos I created the records after I did Platform Initialize

Comment: @RicardoMachado is right, given example create separate unique index by attribute.